# Replacing Tab characters in java files with 4 spaces?

Tags: java, regex, replace

I've had a search about here, and nothing seems to be on the topic of replacing tab characters, I was wondering if anybody can suggest to me any easy ways to replace the tab characters with 4x 'space' characters in over 5,000 files! The files are `.java` files on an SVN server.

I can think of some ways using java (the language i am most comfortable with) to read in the file and replace that way, but I am sure there is probably an easier way of doing this!

Comment: And what encoding are those text files in?

Comment: (The 99.9% convention in the java community is to use 4 spaces for tabs. Comming from C/C++ I appreciate Java's ruling. So reconsider counting à la Mickey Mouse.) There must be Java beautifiers around.

Comment: This seems like a job for sed from unix.

Comment: @JoopEggen Apologies, I keep saying 5 spaces, it is 4.

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg I have come across this in my travels, I am on Mac (work given) but, dare I say it, i'm not very experienced in Unix at all. I'm a windows man!

Comment: Also, are you using Java 8 or Java 7?

Comment: The number of spaces to use will vary from 1 to 4 depending upon the column that the tab occurs. Replacing every tab with 4 spaces will likely not be the format that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually there's no easier way but to open the files, search for tabs,
and replace each one of them with 4 space characters as you need. How do you
do it exactly: this is entirely up to you.

Comment: Eh? `find thedir -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's,\t,     ,g'` -- done (sh* -- how do you input multiple spaces in backquotes?)

Comment: @fge Isn't this doing basically the same: opening the files, looking for tabs in them, replacing them? This is what I meant: that conceptually there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible of course. But you need to know what encoding those files are in.

Quick solution using the shell, provided this is a Unix system (if Windows, well, install cygwin):

```
find thedir -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's,\t,    ,g' {} \;
```

Done.

With Java, well, I do hope you are using Java 7+. If yes this is quite easy: use `Files.walkFileTree()`, collect all regular files into a `List` for instance, and when you have that, perform substitution on each file in the list. DO NOT do this in the `FileVisitor` itself, you might get a `DirectoryIteratorException`.

Links which can help:

- [`SimpleFileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html);
- [`Files.walkFileTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-);
- [`Files.newBufferedReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-);
- [`Files.newBufferedWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

---

Also, and very importantly, DO NOT MODIFY THE FILES INLINE. This will not work. Create a temporary file, write the new contents in it, then rename to the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `Java 7`, it has greatly improved `NIO` package. Reading/writing and accessing files from directories has become very easy. You should give it a go.

Comment: I don't know why someone did the -1 here; using java.nio.file it is indeed quite easy to do so...

Comment: While this answer may contain valid informations it is way too broad for me. It is like link-only-answer but without a link. It looks more like comment than answer. Please include more informations which could solve this problem, suggest classes/methods from that package and describe how you would use them like "I would use `Files.walkFileTree()` to iterate over all files, then ....".

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can reformat all your project files at once. Right click on your root package, and go to Source -> Format.

Comment: You can also use the Anyedit tools plugin http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/ which is able to replace just the tabs. This is less invasive than reformatting the whole file, which might also change other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String fileContent = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

And then:
 `String newFileContent = fileContent.replaceAll("\t", "      ");`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("\t", "    ")
```