# Making changes to every line in a file - Java

Tags: java, file, indentation, lines

I am working on a program that reads 5 different files containing code that is improperly indented. I have to write a method that properly indents the code and prints it to the console and a new file, given a tab size and the names of the input and output files as parameters. My code so far runs through and indents every line and then tries to determine when to indent another tab or unindent.

```
public static void justifyJava( String inputFileName, String outputFileName, 
                                int tabSize ) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String one_tab = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tabSize; i++) {
        one_tab += " ";
        }

    Scanner input = new Scanner( new File (inputFileName));
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream ( new File (outputFileName));
    int lineCount = 0;
    while ( input.hasNextLine() ) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        line = one_tab + line.trim();
        lineCount++;
        if (lineCount == 1){
            line = line.substring(tabSize);
        }
        else if (lineCount == 2){
            Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
                String token = lineScan.next();
                if (token.length() <= 2) {
                    line = line.substring(tabSize);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (line.contains("{") && lineCount > 2){
            System.out.println(line);
            out.println(line);
            line = one_tab + input.nextLine();
            while(!(line.contains("}"))){
                line = one_tab + line;
                System.out.println(line);
                out.println(line);
                line = input.nextLine();
            }
            line = one_tab + line;
        }
        else if (line.contains("}") && input.hasNextLine()){
            line = one_tab + line;
        }
        else if (!(input.hasNextLine())) {
            line = line.substring(tabSize);
        } 
        System.out.println(line);
        out.println(line);                                    
    }            
}
```

This way is becoming very tedious because of how many situations i have to account for especially since the code in these files use different curly brace styles. Essentially all I'm trying to do is indent every line that follows an opening curly brace by one tab and unindent every line that follows a closing curly brace by one tab. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: There are probably thousands pretty printers for every language. So unless this is homework/learning exercise there is no reason to do so... Finding tool (if your editor of choice does not have such functionality for some reason) is definitely easier (and likely more correct) way.

Comment: Totally agree with Alexei.  But if this is not that, consider this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275272/replacing-tab-characters-in-java-files-with-4-spaces

Comment: Recursion is the way to go here. Every time you detect that you have to indent deeper you enter recursion.

Comment: Yeah, its homework I have been stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Determining "how many times" you have to indent a line is the same as knowing how many blocks of code opened before this line. To this end, you detect a new block of code if:

1. The string contains an opening bracket {.
2. The string contains a control statement, e.g. `if`.

The second approach is harder, since you have to determine if the string is actually a control statement and not part of a variable name.

Hence, a simple program, that does not cover every possible coding standard, but will work pretty decently works like this:

1. Search for an opening bracket that does not belong to a comment.
2. When you find it, recursively call the method passing the new indentation size.
3. Return after finding the end of the code block.

Here goes a MWE that works for most simple cases. It is able to detect opening and closing brackets outside strings, and does not search inside comment lines.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaIndent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JavaIndent.justify("path/to/input.java", "path/to/output.java", 4);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found...");
        }
    }

    public static void justify(String inputFileName, String outputFileName,
            int tabSize) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String one_tab = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tabSize; i++) {
            one_tab += " ";
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File(outputFileName));

        JavaIndent.justifyRecursion(one_tab, "", input, out);
    }

    private static String justifyRecursion(String base_tab, String tab, Scanner input, PrintStream out) {
        String line;
        boolean flag_open, flag_close, flag_comment, flag_empty;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine().trim();
            flag_open  = JavaIndent.contains(line, "{");
            flag_close = JavaIndent.contains(line, "}");
            flag_empty = line.length() == 0;
            flag_comment = (flag_empty) ? false : line.charAt(0) == '/';
            if (flag_comment || flag_empty) {
                out.println(tab + line);
            } else if (flag_close) {
                return line;
            } else if (flag_open) {
                out.println(tab + line + "ENTERED OPEN");
                line = JavaIndent.justifyRecursion(base_tab, tab + base_tab, input, out);
                out.println(tab + line);

                // Handles statements like } else { and sequences of these.
                flag_open = JavaIndent.contains(line, "{");
                while (flag_open) {
                    line = JavaIndent.justifyRecursion(base_tab, tab + base_tab, input, out);
                    out.println(tab + line);
                    flag_open = JavaIndent.contains(line, "{");
                }
            } else {
                // Just a regular line, nothing special
                out.println(tab + line);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private static boolean contains(String line, String sequence) {
        String current = "";
        char ch, last_ch = ' ';
        int count_quotation = 0;
        ArrayList<String> code_without_strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < line.length(); ++k) {
            ch = line.charAt(k);
            if (ch == '"' && count_quotation == 0 && last_ch != '\'') {
                code_without_strings.add(current);
                current = "";
                ++count_quotation;
            } else if (ch == '"' && count_quotation == 1) {
                if (last_ch != '\\') {
                    count_quotation = 0;
                }
            }
            if (count_quotation == 0) {
                current += ch;
            }
            last_ch = ch;
        }
        code_without_strings.add(current);

        for (String code : code_without_strings) {
            if (code.contains(sequence))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, one still needs to consider statements such as this:

```
if (condition)
    System.out.println("This should be indented, but it won't be...");
```

and this:

```
/**
 * This is just a comment, but the program will indent from here on {.
 */
```

Try using JavaIndent to indent JavaIndent.java and verify that at the very end you will get

```
if (code.contains(sequence))
return true;
```

instead of

```
if (code.contains(sequence))
    return true;
```